# jQuery Mobile Calendar Component

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a requirement to add appointments details to my jQuery Mobile powered mobile application. I need something like Google Calendar.

What are the possible calendar components I can look into??

I know Sage's [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) is a wonderful tool but it doesn't offer weekly view, in addition we can't have color codes and events written inside the calendar cells like Google Calendar.

Can anyone please suggest me to find a good components even if I have to pay I don't mind. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of fairly populare calendars with what you need:

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Mobiscroll Calendar Control](http://mobiscroll.com/component/calendar) a try. It comes with a Calendar View plus it works with Date & Time Spinners as well.

It also has a jQuery Mobile Theme which inherits jQM swatches.